# Unpack tuples from list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I would like to unpack the variables from a list of list of tuples. I have made some attempts but could not reach a solution.

Here is a list of points. I would like to unpack each variable inside `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4` during each iteration of the sublists so that during each iteration each variable gets assigned.

For example in the first iteration, I would expect:

```
p1=(0,0)
p2=(1,0)
p3=(2,0)
p4=(0,1)
```

In the next iteration:

```
p1=(0,0)
p2=(1,0)
p3=(2,0)
p4=(2,1)
```

```
points=[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1)],[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]]
        
for i in points:
    for j in i:
         p1=j[0],j[1]
         p2=j[0],j[1]
         p3=j[0],j[1]
         p4=j[0],j[1]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you give a simpler example of the input and expected output, and could you tell us exactly where you are stuck?

Comment: What is 'sub'? You have error in your code.

Comment: Are you looking for `for p1, p2, p3, p4 in points`?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Each element of `points` is a list of tuples that can be unpacked, like so:

```py
for p1, p2, p3, p4 in points:
    print(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

This outputs:

```py
(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (0, 1)
(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0) (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected sub to points and I fixed the index that was out of bounds when unpacking p2.

```
points=[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1)],[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]]
        
for i in points:
    for j in i:
         p1=j[0],j[1]
         p2=j[0],j[1]
         p3=j[0],j[1]
         p4=j[0],j[1]
        
        
    print (p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be nice.